# New to Python and instantly confused

Tags: python

I'm taking a python course on codecademy at the moment and decided to try run a simple program on my computer from the terminal.

I created a basic program based on simple if, elif, else statements, really simple code as I'm trying to reinforce the basics that I'm learning, the goal is to form a response, if you have more than 49 credits, you get a congratulatory response and so forth...

```
firstName = raw_input("Enter your first name: ")
lastName = raw_input("Enter your last name: ")
excellenceCredits = raw_input("Enter the amount of excellence credits 
you have so far: ")

if excellenceCredits > 49 and len(firstName) >= 10:
    print "Well done " + firstName + " " + lastName + " on the 
excellence endorsement, feel proud! You also have an impressive long 
name!"
elif excellenceCredits > 49 and len(firstName) < 10:
    print "Well done " + firstName + " " + lastName + " on the 
excellence endorsement, feel proud!"
elif excellenceCredits < 50 and excellenceCredits > 40:
    print "So close " + firstName + ", better luck next time, I bet 
the " + lastName + "s are so proud of you!"
else:
    print "Keep working hard, you never know what's around the corner..."
```

The problem is whenever I run the program from the terminal and enter an excellenceCredits value less than 50, it still prints the wrong response, this is probably really simple, but I just can't see whats wrong with the code.

Comment: What specifically is printed, and what do you expect? For what specific value of `excellenceCredits`?

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` parses the user's input as a `str` type, not an `int`.

Try:

```
int(raw_input("Enter the amount of excellence credits you have so far: "))
```

to get closer to your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks heaps, funny how a little thing like this can get you scratching your head, if only codecademy explained how raw_input works better, obviously I shall have to dig deeper in my studies, but nevertheless thank you for saving me some time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing integers (49, 50, etc.) to the *string* value of `excellenceCredits`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/3857192) has more details.

To compare your `raw_input` as an integer, convert it by passing it to the built-in function [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
excellenceCredits = int(raw_input("Enter the amount..."))
```

Comment: As an aside, if you're just starting out with Python, you might want to look into using Python 3 instead of Python 2 There are more details on the differences [here, on the Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: Thank you, I see where I went wrong, didn't realise raw_input was only for strings and not numbers, can you use input or is that not accepted as a viable solution?

Comment: @TobyMeyrick: Don't use Py2's `input`. It's swatting flies with a shotgun, because it includes an implicit `eval`, which can execute arbitrary code (e.g. the user enters `__import__("shutil").rmtree("/")` or whatever, and now you're deleting any files where you have write access for the parent directory). When you want an `int`, convert to `int`, don't allow arbitrary code to run.

Answer (score 0):

You are going on a good way, just need to take care when the `raw_input` you need is of `int` datatype.
You need to do the following when its datatype is `int`.

```
excellenceCredits = int(raw_input("Enter the amount of excellence credits 
you have so far: "))
```

> Python 2.x
>   There are two functions to get user input, called `input` and `raw_input`. The difference is, `raw_input` doesn't evaluate the data and returns as it in string form. But, `input` will evaluate whatever you entered and the result of evaluation will be returned.

`raw_input` gives you a string you must convert to an `integer` or `float` before making any numeric comparison.

> Python 3.x

`Python 3.x`'s `input` and `Python 2.x`'s `raw_input` are similar and `raw_input` is not available in `Python 3.x`.